# Invalid syntax. I save my text file on my desktop calling it file.

Tags: python

Create graph:-

```
def loadGraphFile(file):
    graph = []
    for line in file:
        contents = line.split()
        movieName = contents[0]
        actorNames = [contents[i]+ " " + contents[i+1] for i in range(1, len(contents), 2)]        
        movieNode = findNode(graph, movieName)
        if movieNode == None:
            movieNode = mkNode(movieName)
            graph.append(movieNode)
        for actorName in actorNames:            
            actorNode = findNode(graph,actorName)
        if actorNode == None:
            actorNode = mkNode(actorName)
            graph.append(actorNode)
        actorNode.neighbor.append(movieNode)
        movieNode.neighbor.append(actorNode)
        return graph

def loadGraphFileName('file.text'):
   return loadGraphFile(Open('file.text'))
```

Comment: Please show the exact error message. And are you sure you have a function called `Open`? Shouldn't it be `open` (all lower case)?

Comment: Below is the error it shows when compile my project line 37
    def loadGraphFileName('file.text'):
                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 2):

You declared your function wrong:

```
def loadGraphFileName('file.text'):  # change this
   return loadGraphFile(Open('file.text'))
```

To this:

```
def loadGraphFileName():  # You don't use it anyway
   return loadGraphFile(Open('file.text'))
```

Or:

```
def loadGraphFileName(filename='file.text'):  # file.text will be the default. if you give an parameter with it, filename will change to that parameter
   return loadGraphFile(Open(filename)) # And use it here
```

Comment: Thank it did fix my invalid syntax error but it is not reading my text file

Comment: What is the exact name of your textfile? it propably txt and not text. Also are they in the same directory?

Comment: Have an question when I run my program I am getting an error: 
%run "C:/Users/******/Desktop/KB2.py"

Comment: Could you place the full stacktrace in the question please?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have literals as function params

You can instead do

```
def loadGraphFileName(f = 'file.txt'):
   return loadGraphFile(Open(f))
```

Comment: Thank it did fix my invalid syntax error but it is not reading my text file

Comment: @JamesSmith  Where is your Python program, Is it in the same place as file.txt?

Comment: Well in my file.txt shows few names from famous actors and actress... Do I need to create an main method

Comment: @JamesSmith The location of both the py program and file.txt must be the same

Comment: I am programming my python code on CANOPY.. I am new to python but when I program java or C++ I can easy drag my text file into the project... But how can I do this for python.

Comment: Is the name of your file file.text or file.txt?

Comment: The name of my file is file.txt from notepad I save on my desktop

Comment: then use `def loadGraphFileName(f = 'file.txt'):
   return loadGraphFile(Open(f))`

Comment: @JamesSmith Do revert back if it solved your problem

Comment: Have an question when I run my program I am getting an error: 
%run "C:/Users/******/Desktop/KB2.py"

Comment: Actually that was the error when I compile my code.

Comment: @JamesSmith You are welcome. But before asking another question, search SO on topics like change directory in python, etc. You might find an answer. And remember to close this question !!! All the best

Comment: I m now trying to ask the user to enter names from the text-file. I create a code but I am getting error    '      '